# Wordpress Custom URL rewriting

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I need little help for url rewriting in wordpress.

basically what i need:

mydomain.com/mysomewordpresspost

mydomain.com/parentpage/subpage

to

mydomain.com/global/mysomewordpresspost.

mydomain.com/global/subpage

Basically want to add "global" in url
and also for subpages, categories, post etc etc.

mean all long url short to "global"

No want to show categorname in url and parent page name in url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily, Just add like this in your Permalink Settings->Custom Structure

```
/global/%postname%/
```

Comment: See i apply you custom permalink but the url is redirecting:

http://webdesignerart.com/survey/global/about-rendevous/

redirecting to

http://webdesignerart.com/survey/about-rendevous/

http://webdesignerart.com/survey/ is main url not worry for this i installed wordpress in survey folder.

Comment: i Want to do apposite:

http://webdesignerart.com/survey/about-rendevous/

have to redirect

http://webdesignerart.com/survey/global/about-rendevous/

means all long url string short to global string.

Comment: @Abdullah got ur problem now--- u r using Nginx server......... Pretty permalinks are available under:

    Apache web server with the mod_rewrite module
    Microsoft IIS 7+ web server with the URL Rewrite 1.1+ module and PHP 5 running as FastCGI
    Microsoft IIS 6+ using ASAPI_Rewrite
    Lighttpd using a 404 handler or mod_rewrite (See Also http://josephscott.org/archives/2010/06/wordpress-pretty-permalinks-with-nginx/)

Comment: @Abdullah check your Nginx server settings :) i think this si going to resolve your matter now :)

Comment: :( Server settings, My server is apache server. Their is no way through .htaccess :(

Comment: Ok now its work in my new server :) please see.
http://www.avanzasolutions.com/123456/global/hello-world

it works in page type post

when i add page:
http://www.avanzasolutions.com/123456/sample-page/sample-child-page

the permalink not replace the sample-page string to global.
Please help.

Comment: Yeah thank.you mate for your help but it help me 50% yet :( any idea for pages.

Comment: @Abdullah i think when custom structure option is choose pages are automatically converted in the requested manner..let mw know the issue

Comment: you can see this:

http://www.avanzasolutions.com/123456/sample-page
http://www.avanzasolutions.com/123456/sample-page/sample-child-page

I want this:

http://www.avanzasolutions.com/123456/global/sample-page
http://www.avanzasolutions.com/123456/global/sample-child-page


This is what i want.

Comment: @Abdullah for page customization you can use this plugin and let me know if u face any issue http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/ ..waiting for the green tick ;)

Comment: Yeah i use that, But i want thing done automatically,Custom post type working like charm in my situation :) thanks for your help mate.